# What is a sensible way to combine multiple Jaro-Winkler calculations?

Tags: database, math, fuzzy-logic, jaro-winkler

Let's say I am comparing two individuals, each with a first name, last name, postal code, address(line1), address(line2), and phone number. These all have varying reliability and importance for determining a match.

I can generate a J-W distance for each field with no issue. How can I combine these to get a sensible rating for the similarity of two individuals?

What I have thought of so far is just to weigh the different JW ratings to an amount proportionate to their relevance, and then take a weighted average. I feel like there must be some better techniques.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage (esp Felligi Sunter method)

Comment: This is incredible, thanks a ton.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak, can you post sample code for what you ended up doing? Did you use the weighted average or something else?